# Removing string from one file using another in c#?

Tags: c#

I have two files namely, file.txt and database.xml

file.txt looks like

```
Istanbul
Moscow
London
Saint Petersburg
Berlin
Madrid
Kiev
Rome
Paris
```

database.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<city-group>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <city>London</city>
    <city>Boulder</city>
    <city>Mumbai</city>
    <city>Quebec</city>
    .....
    .....
</city-group>
```

How do I search contents of each line in file.txt with database.xml and remove lines if there is a data match between them? i.e. after the program ends the file.txt should look like

```
Istanbul
Moscow
Saint Petersburg
Berlin
Madrid
Kiev
Rome
```

Since both Paris and London are present inside the nodes **city** in database.xml, they are removed from file.txt.
What is the fastest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read all entries of text file in a string array using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()`. Load your XML into an `XElement`. Then use LINQ to find array elements that are not in the `XElement` children. I can post the code too, but it should be simple.

### Edit

This should basically do it for you:

```
var FileEntries = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("TEXT_FILE_PATH");
var XMLEntries = XElement.Load("XML_FILE_PATH").Elements().Select(xx => xx.Value);
var list = FileEntries.Where(e => !XMLEntries.Contains(e));
```

Comment: I get an error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** in line 2 of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for your need.

- Create a class for city list and deserialize database.xml file to an object
- Read file.txt line by line and check each line with city list read from database.xml
- If city name not contains in city list, append it to a string builder
- Write dtring builder content to file.txt

  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;

  namespace ConsoleApplication1
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  ```
          CityList cityList = new CityList();
          XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CityList));
          using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("database.txt", FileMode.Open))
          {
              cityList = (CityList)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
          }

          using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
          {
              string line;
              while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
                  if (!cityList.cities.Any(line.Contains))
                      sb.AppendLine(line);
              }
          }

          File.WriteAllText("file.txt", sb.ToString());
      }
  }


  [XmlRoot("city-group")]
  public class CityList
  {
      [XmlElement("city")]
      public string[] cities { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but isn't it a bit complicated for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution

```
[XmlRoot("city-group")]
public class Citites
{
    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string[] City { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // 1. read all city's names from xml file
        Citites cities;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("database.xml"))
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Citites));
            cities = (Citites)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
        // 2. read current file and open temp file for insert not matched city 
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (StreamReader rw = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
        {
            {
                // while of not end
                while (rw.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    // read next line
                    string city = rw.ReadLine();
                    if (!cities.City.Contains(city))
                    { 
                        // the city's name no matched, insert to temp file
                        sw.WriteLine(city);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // 3. replace the current file with a temp file
        File.Delete("file.txt");
        File.Move(tempFile, "file.txt");
    }
}
```

If *file.txt* is very large then immediately reading all the lines is a bad decision. This will load the RAM
In this solution, we read line by line and not load content of file whole.

Comment: what is the `[XmlRoot("city-group")]` outside the class?

Comment: [XmlRoot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlroot(v=vs.110).aspx) is attribute for setting a root element name when object serializes by XmlSerializer. In your example it value is _city-group_